# Display image with select list APEX

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle-apex

I have two items: a Select List and a Display Image. The Select List has three values for the user to choose from. If the user selects on of the values then the Image View will show a related image with the selected value and if the selected value of the Select List will switch also change the picture.
I tried putting the script in the section: JavaScript -> "Function and Global Variable Declaration" of the page, but not run.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">   
function setValueDisplayImage(){
    if ($("#SELECT_LIST").val() == 1) {
            $("#DISPLAY_IMAGE").val('http://www.some.com/img1.jpg');
    } else if ($("#SELECT_LIST").val() == 2) {
            $("#DISPLAY_IMAGE").val('https://www.some.com/img2.jpg');
    } else if ($("#SELECT_LIST").val() == 3){
            $("#DISPLAY_IMAGE").val('http://www.some.com/img3.jpg');
    } 
}</script>
```

Comment: You can use dynamic action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jquery [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on) like,

```
$(function(){
    $("#SELECT_LIST").on('change', function(){
       var val=this.value;
       if(val==1 || val==2 || val==3){
           $("#DISPLAY_IMAGE").val('http://www.some.com/img'+val+'.jpg');
       }       
    });
});
```

```js
$(function(){
    $("#SELECT_LIST").on('change', function(){
       var val=this.value;
       if(val==1 || val==2 || val==3){
           $("#DISPLAY_IMAGE").val('http://www.some.com/img'+val+'.jpg');
       }       
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="SELECT_LIST">
  <option value="1">First Image</option>
  <option value="2">Second Image</option>
  <option value="3">Third Image</option>
</select>
<br/>
<input id="DISPLAY_IMAGE" style="width:250px;"/>
```

And if your `DISPLAY_IMAGE` element is an `img` then your need to use [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr) to change the image src like,

```js
$(function(){
    $("#SELECT_LIST").on('change', function(){
       var val=this.value;
       if(val){
           $("#DISPLAY_IMAGE").attr('src','http://placehold.it/250x'+val);
       }       
    }).change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="SELECT_LIST">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="100">First Image</option>
  <option value="150">Second Image</option>
  <option value="200">Third Image</option>
</select>
<br/>
<img id="DISPLAY_IMAGE"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Rohan Kumar with the second jquery code did what I needed, thank you very much.                                                                                                https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=81693:1:101880908609086:::::

Comment: Dear how i can do that but in dynamic select list , i have a static file for country flag , and country table with all country code , the country code same country flag name  how i select used this image in select list